# cryptojs aes encryption does not match with php

Tags: javascript, php, encryption, cryptojs

I want to encrypt and decrypt data between client and server so using cryptojs. but cryptojs does work properly

1. it returns different values every time it runs when using AES but somehow decrypt properly.
2. encrypted value does not match with php value.

php

```
$simple_string = "this is my test";
$ciphering = "AES-256-CBC";
$options = 0;
$encryption_iv = '0123456789012345';
$encryption_key = "password";
$encryption = openssl_encrypt($simple_string, $ciphering, $encryption_key, $options, $encryption_iv);

echo "Encrypted String: " . $encryption . " <br>"; //  XkuEMQ6oPwCf4JFb7TlPgw==

$decryption=openssl_decrypt ($encryption, $ciphering, $encryption_key, $options, $encryption_iv);
echo "Decrypted String: " . $decryption; // this is my test
```

js

```
    function encrypt(msg, pass, iv) {
        var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(msg, pass, { iv: iv, keySize: 256, mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC, });
        var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, pass, { iv: iv, keySize: 256, mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC, });

        console.log(encrypted.toString()); // U2FsdGVkX19vi6PRshrz1aB0FSy0q4FNWvl3kkphsHs=
        console.log(decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8)); // this is my test
    }
    console.log(encrypt("this is my test", "password", "0123456789012345"));
```

i want javascript function(encrypt and decrypt) for sending and receiving server data using cryptojs.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just use HTTPS:

Comment: already using HTTPS but i want  to encrypt data for man in middle attack

Comment: Can you PHP decrypt your JS, and can your JS decrypt your PHP? If so, you should be good.

Comment: @Chris Haas No. that's a problem. js function doesn't decrypt php encryption

Comment: Both codes use different key derivations. In the PHP code, a too short key is expanded to the required size with 0x00 values (32 bytes because of aes-256-cbc). In the CryptoJS code, the key derivation function `EVP_BytesToKey()` is applied implicitly.

Comment: In order for the CryptoJS code to interpret the key material as key (i.e. no key derivation function is applied), it must be passed as `WordArray`.

Comment: @Topaco please can u give me any examples.  I don't know much about encryption and decryption

Comment: I just need one simple  and working example.

Comment: Please see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the CryptoJS code compatible with the PHP code, in the CryptoJS code the too short key material must be extended with 0x00 values to the specified key length (note that if the key material were too long, it would simply have to be truncated to the specified key length).
Since aes-256-cbc is used in the example, it must be extended to 32 bytes  and imported into a `WordArray` using the Latin1 encoder.
The IV is to be imported into a `WordArray` in an analogous way:

```php
console.log(encrypt("this is my test", CryptoJS.enc.Latin1.parse("password".padEnd(32, '\0')), CryptoJS.enc.Latin1.parse("0123456789012345")));
```

what gives as output:

```
XkuEMQ6oPwCf4JFb7TlPgw==
this is my test
```

in accordance with the PHP code.

Comment: thanks thanks thanks thanks a lot. you saved my day. can i use Utf8 instead of Latin1 ?

Comment: @lapppy - For your key and IV  there is no difference between UTF-8 or Latin1 (ISO-8859-1). For a general compatibility you have to choose the encoding in the CryptoJS code which is also used in the PHP code. You can easily check the encoding in the PHP code e.g. with `print(bin2hex("§"))`. Latin1 returns 0xa7, UTF-8 returns 0xc2a7.

Comment: thanks for replay .can u tell is there `GCM mode` in cryptojs? if no is there any other library for the same

Comment: @lapppy - CryptoJS does not support GCM. Here is a list of JavaScript crypto libraries: https://gist.github.com/jo/8619441. Some of them support GCM, e.g. WebCryptoAPI or sjcl. For further questions please post a new question on SO. Note that library recommendations are off topic on SO. Thx.